# Getting ID insted of name from For Each Loop WordPress :(

Tags: php, wordpress

Please Help me! I want to show the Name of agent, but unfortunately, I get value instead of Agent name. I am new to PHP. This the code. What I do, i use this code.

```
<?php
if( !empty( $wpc_agents ) ) {
  $agent = $wpcargo->get_shipment_agent( $post->ID );
  ?>
  <select name="agent_fields">
    <option value=""><?php _e('-- Select One --', 'wpcargo' ); ?></option>
    <?php
    foreach ($wpc_agents as $val) {
      ?>
      <option value="<?php _e(sanitize_text_field($val->ID)); ?>" <?php selected( $agent, $val->ID ); ?> ><?php _e(sanitize_text_field($val->display_name)); ?></option>
  <?php
  }
  ?></select><?php
}
?>
```

And display value with this code

```
$agent  = get_post_meta($shipment_id, 
    'agent_fields', true);


<div class="col-4">
    <p class="label">
      <?php _e('Agent Name', 'wpcargo'); ?>
    </p>
    <p class="label-info"><?php echo $agent; ?></p>
  </div>
```

But this `$agent` giving me the ID of the agent instead of his name :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search for the declaration of `get_shipment_agent`, is it from a plugin? There might be another function to retrieve the name.

Comment: Hi alariva, Thank you so much for you reply. Yes it's from plugin which name is wpcargo.

Comment: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wpcargo/trunk/admin/classes/class-wpcargo.php There is a `function agent_display_name( $userID )`. As long as you can get the userID I think you should be able to get what you want. also `agent_id('display_name', $userID)`